# Generate vector of correlated value from normal distribution in R

Tags: r, statistics

I want to generate 3 correlated numbers from normal distribution in R. What I have is matrix of variance and covariance between variables. So if I will draw my 3 numbers they should be correlated too. I have no idea how I should do it in R language.

Comment: You are dealing with a multivariate normal distribution. There are many packages that implement it (you can perform a quick to google search to see some of them). For instance, the `mvtnorm` package has the `rmvnorm` which should be what you are looking for.

Comment: You may also use `mvrnorm` function from `MASS` package, read the following old post on r-bloggers:
https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-generate-correlated-random-numbers/

Comment: You could use copula for such problem: https://datascienceplus.com/modelling-dependence-with-copulas/